# Splunk subsearch is not returning the data I expect it to return

Tags: splunk

I have:

1. index="myIndex"
2. source="mySource1"
3. source="mySource2"

**mySource1 example**

```
2023-02-01 17:00:01 - Naam van gebruiker: hank - Rol van gebruiker: operator

2023-02-02 17:00:01 - Naam van gebruiker: skylar - Rol van gebruiker: operator

2023-02-03 17:00:01 - Naam van gebruiker: walt - Rol van gebruiker: operator

2023-02-02 17:00:01 - Naam van gebruiker: skylar - Rol van gebruiker: administrator

2023-02-03 17:00:01 - Naam van gebruiker: walt - Rol van gebruiker: administrator
```

**mySource2 example**

```
2023-02-06 13:49:57,654 User:hank The user is authenticated and logged in.

2023-02-07 13:49:57,654 User:skylar The user is authenticated and logged in.

2023-02-08 13:49:57,654 User:walt The user is authenticated and logged in.

2023-02-03 13:49:57,654 User:hank The user is authenticated and logged in.

2023-02-02 13:49:57,654 User:skylar The user is authenticated and logged in.

2023-02-01 13:49:57,654 User:walt The user is authenticated and logged in.
```

In Splunk I need a dashboard, with a statisticstable, looking like this:

```
USER, LATEST
hank, 2023-02-03 13:49:57,654 User:hank The user is authenticated and logged in.
skylar, 2023-02-02 13:49:57,654 User:skylar The user is authenticated and logged in.
walt, 2023-02-01 13:49:57,654 User:walt The user is authenticated and logged in
```

Where USER is column 1 and LATEST column 2. The purpose of the table is to show the user id's (found in mySource1) and show the latest login event (found in mySource2) so that you can tell when each user last logged in.

Initially I tried this:

```
index="myIndex" 
source="mySource1"
| fields _time, _raw
| rex "Naam van gebruiker: (?<USER>.+) -"
| dedup USER
| table USER
| sort USER
| join type=left 
[ search
    index="myIndex"
    source="mySource2"
    "User:myUserID The user is authenticated and logged in." 
    | stats latest(_raw)
]
```

But I found out that I the second search, returns data to the first search. Also, I did not fetch the name from the second search. I later tried the following:

```
index="myIndex" source="mySource2"
    "The user is authenticated and logged in."
| rex "User:(?<USER>\w+) The user is authenticated and logged in."
| search [search index="myIndex" 
    source="mySource1"
    | rex "Naam van gebruiker: (?<USER>.+) -"
    | dedup USER
    | table USER
    | sort USER
    | format] 
| stats latest(_raw) by USER
```

But this does not return any data. I tried running both searches seperately, and when I do, they return the data I need:

```
index="myIndex"  source="mySource2"
    "The user is authenticated and logged in."
| rex "User:(?<USER>\w+) The user is authenticated and logged in."
| table USER
| dedup USER

index="myIndex" 
    source="mySource1"
    | rex "Naam van gebruiker: (?<USER>.+) -"
    | dedup USER
    | table USER
    | sort USER
```

But once combined, no data is returned.

How do I manage to return the data and get the desired table of results?

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention, I also need to show users who have a role (source1) but have never logged in (not found in source2). Hence mySource1 is used.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to combine it all in one go:

```
index=ndx (source=source1 OR source=source2)
| rex field=_raw "Naam[^:]+:\s(?<user1>\S+)
| rex field=_raw "User:(?<user2>\S+)\s(?<msg>.+)
| eval user=coalesce(user1,user2)
| stats max(_time) as _time latest(msg) as msg by user
```

What this does: extract two field (`user1` & `user2`) from your two sources

`coalesce` them into one field named "`user`"

Report the most recent `msg` for that `user` and the most recent `_time` you have an event for

---

(You *should* be able to abbreviate this slightly by using the same named field extraction (`user`) instead of two with a `coalesce`, I just wanted it to be clear)

#### edit to add users that have never logged in

```
index=ndx source=source1
| rex field=_raw "Naam[^:]+:\s(?<user>\S+)[^:]+:\s(?<role>\w+)"
| stats values(role) as roles by user
| append
    [search index=ndx source=source2
    | rex field=_raw "User:(?<user>\S+)\s(?<msg>.+)
    | stats latest(msg) as msg max(_time) as msg_time by user ]
| stats values(*) as * by user
| where isnull(msg)
```

Here we're looking for a list of all users that have roles first, then `append`ing the latest message for each user, then `stats values()` them together and throw away all entries that don't have a `msg` field via the `where` clause

Comment: Hi I tried your solution, I get the events from both sources but I don't get results in the statistics. I tried changing the syntax of both rex extractions to match mine I used in OP (but used user1 and user2). When I run that, I get a list of statistics showing me usernames in the field user, time (from source1) in the field _time, and nothing in the field msg.

Comment: @NiekJonkman - I did have a typo of `latest(lsg) as msg` instead of `latest(msg) as msg`. Corrected that. Try now.

Comment: This works, however, it only shows users that, at one time, logged in. Is it possible to also show the users from source1 that do not occur in source2, as an empty field? So that USER is filled, and LATEST remains empty? To show users with a role that have never logged in.

Comment: @NiekJonkman - please see if that edit gets you closer

Comment: thanks for your help so far, but the latest returns the same. With or without | where isnull(msg) , only the hosts that are found in both source1 and source2 are shown. I am going to see if I maybe can change the source files to include all data into one sourcefile instead